# How does a browser transfers a cookie to server?

Tags: browser, cookies

I want to understand that how a web browser transfers cookie to the server. Say i am requesting. Google.com will it just transfers the cookie which were created by google.com domain or will it transfer all the cookies. If it transfers just the google ones how does it reads the domain information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install Live HTTP Headers to see how browsers "communicate" with servers. Basically, cookies are stored in a way that whenever you visit a site, you browser will look for cookies whose domains matches the domain of the site you are visiting.

If you are using Firefox, you may also install the Web Developer Add-on for you to manage cookies easily. You will see that cookies have these fields:

```
Name    [name]
Value   [value]
Host    [domains where the cookie will be valid]
Path    [paths within the domain where the cookie will be valid]
...
```

Your browser will then append a `Cookie:` field in the HTTP Header whose value correspond to cookie names and their values whenever you visit a site with a matching Host and Path.

```
Cookie: [name]=[value]
```

Whenever a website wants to "store" a cookie in your computer, it send a `Set-Cookie:` header which your browsers will interpret and create or update the corresponding cookie

```
Set-Cookie: [name]=[value]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "cookies whose domains matches the" what if there is no domain set in the cookie? Will it be sent to all the requests.

Comment: Cookies with no Host or Domain will never be sent

Comment: @ronlando what's the significance of path attribute.

Comment: If you visit a site `(example.com)` and they sent the `path` to `/path`, then your cookie will be sent if you visit `example.com/path` but not when you visit `example.com/other_path`

Comment: +1 for csrf info. Can you suggest me the right approach for autologin.

Comment: I really haven't created an autologin for my sites. Sorry. But if you want some implementation details for CSRF, here is the link: [OWASP CSF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out... http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

To answer your question - web sites can read cookies only published under it's domain..

Comment: can i manually change the information like domain and other stuff in cookie using some tool like firebug to send false information?

Comment: actually i am trying to write a autologin functionality and thinking of using cookies. Is it the right approach do you guys see and problem with that may be some security issue.

Comment: auto logins are vulnerable to Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) since credentials are stored in a cookie. You'd have to implement extra security measures especially in areas where clients will do transactions

Answer (score 0):

It will only transfer the cookies related to Google. When Cookies are received, they are specified to operate on a domain or set of domains (such as *.google.com).